# Linq groupby with count of particular column

Tags: linq

I m populating the datatable from a sql query using c#. It has two columns

```
env  issud
Dit    x
Dit   x
Sit   y
```

The output of the linq query should group env and count of issue
    Dit 2
    Sit  1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
var query = table.GroupBy(x => x.env)
                 .Select(g => new { Env = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Or as a query expression:

```
var query = from row in table
            group row by row.env into g
            select new { Env = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```